# Java: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, constructor, nosuchelementexception

I have a problem and don't know what to do. Here's the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Auto.<init>(Auto.java:32)
    at Auto.main(Auto.java:22)
```

And that's my Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Auto {
    private String Marke1; 
    String Modell1; 
    String Farbe1; 
    double Höhe;
    double Breite;
    double Länge;
    int Tueren = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Auto!");

        Auto myFerrari = new Auto();
        myFerrari.einfacheNachricht();
        Auto myOpel = new Auto();
        myOpel.einfacheNachricht();
    }

    public Auto() {
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die Marke ihres Autos an");
        Marke1 = r.nextLine()
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie das Modell ihres Autos an");             
        Modell1 = r.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die Farbe ihres Autos an");
        Farbe1 = r.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie an, wiehoch ihr Auto ist");
        Höhe = r.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie an, wie breit ihr Auto ist");
        Breite = r.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie an, wie lang ihr Auto ist"); 
        Länge = r.nextDouble();
        r.close();
    }

    public Auto(String aMarke1, String aModell1, String aFarbe1, double aHöhe, double aBreite, double aLänge) { 
        Marke1 = aMarke1; 
        Modell1 = aModell1;
        Farbe1 = aFarbe1;
        Höhe = aHöhe;
        Breite = aBreite;
        Länge = aLänge;
    }

    public int getSitzreihen() { 
        return Tueren = 2; 
    }

    public void einfacheNachricht() {
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Automarke: " + Marke1);
        System.out.println("Modell: " + Modell1);
        System.out.println("Farbe: " + Farbe1);
        System.out.println("Sitzreihen: " + getSitzreihen());
        System.out.println("Volumen: " +(Höhe * Breite * Länge) +"m²" ) ;
        System.out.println("Ihr " + Farbe1 + "er " + Marke1 + " " + Modell1 + " hat ein Volumen von "+(Höhe * Breite * Länge) +"m²");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat the code in your question. It's unreadable at the moment.

Comment: Which line is line 32? Also, why do you have `return Tueren = 2`? Do you mean `return Tueren == 2` (assignment vs equality)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing a `Scanner` causes the underlying `InputStream` to be closed also. As there is only one `System.in`, any newly created `Scanner` objects will not be able to read from the same stream:

```
r.close();
```

This line should be removed

See: [Do not create multiple buffered wrappers on a single InputStream](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+InputStream)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the next line exists before, use `hasNextLine()` before calling `nextLine()`