# Scanner Skipping Over my Opportunity to Input

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

while this may be entirely trivial my lack of experience has rendered me stumped due to this: with this line of code

```
String a = scanner.nextLine();
```

I am shown the following error

```
 java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

I was under the impression that when operations involving the use of Scanner data follow the use of a scanner it will wait for input. This scanner simply leaves me with no chance to enter my input leaving me with operations attempting to use data that does not exist.

Here is the complete relevant code. Forget its inefficiency.

```
System.out.println(FactBank_QA.qA[ourRANDOM]);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        if (scanner.hasNext()){
            String a = scanner.next();
            char b = (char)a.charAt(0);
            if (b == '*') System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println(FactBank_QA.qA[ourRANDOM+1]);
        char c; String f = "0";
        do{
            if (scanner.hasNext()){
                f= scanner.next();
            }
                c = (char)f.charAt(0);
        }while(c != 1 || c != 2);
        if (c == 1) {           
        FactBank_QA.qA[ourRANDOM] = ""; 
        FactBank_QA.qA[ourRANDOM+1] = "";
        }
```

The exception is coming from the first, the second isn't reached
Thanks for the tip too.
-Updated the code and removed a .close
I no longer receive errors (!) however the second Scanner and subsequent 'if' are now non-functional.
I did have one .close() but have removed it, this fixed the first use of 'scanner'

Comment: can u share the complete code?

Comment: btw with Scanner you need to first check if there is a next line using method hasNextLine()

Comment: @WilliamBrun, is the exception being thrown at `scanner.nextLine()` or is it at `zcanner.nextLine()`? BTW you shouldn't need 2 scanners bound to `System.in`. One should be enough.

Comment: @WilliamBrun, PS: Did you create any other objects bound to `System.in` and/or call `close()` on any of them?

Comment: I tried running the above code (except for modifying the parts that referenced `FactBank_QA`) and it worked fine.  I suspect something the program did before the above code snippet that is affecting things.

Comment: Could an overuse of static methods cause this? I have no objects, only raw data an a lot of variables...

Comment: SNIP: Did you fix your datatype issues? (see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, be cautious of where you call `close()`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017047/1127098) is a good reference.

You also seem to have a logic error here:

```
do{
    if (scanner.hasNext()){
        f= scanner.next();
    }
        c = (char)f.charAt(0);
}while(c != 1 || c != 2);
```

`c` is a `char`. Remember that `'0'` is very different than `0`. You may instead want: `while(c != '1' || c != '2');`. You might need to update other areas of your code as well.

Another logic error, what if I press enter without typing anything? (psst: `f.charAt(0)`)

One more: `while(c != '1' || c != '2')` is an infinite loop, since `c` can never be simultaneously equal to '1' and '2'.

Comment: That is it! Thank you. To keep with the commenting protocol though I must ask, is there a better method with which to get the first char of a word, I found this on an old forum and was wondering if more modern java has a specific 'first letter' method available. Also since I used the charAt(0) twice it may be better to make a method that performs that function to prevent redundancies.

Comment: I can't think of a better way than `str.charAt()`. Just be careful to not read outside the bounds of the string as I mentioned! Also, `(char)str.charAt(0)` is redundant. `str.charAt(0)` is sufficient.

Comment: PS: Defining an entire function to extract the first letter of a string is the equivalent of building a robot to push a button (inefficient and completely unnecessary). What is so confusing about `str.charAt(0)`? There is nothing wrong with calling a function twice. PPS: Even if you did create a function, eg `getFirstLetter()`, you would still be calling THAT function twice, no?

Comment: I agree. I was just wondering if there was some kind of programmer etiquette notion that would suggest such calls are useless. I appreciate the help though, this is all in the name of learning!